Segmentation Fault When Running Jest Tests with SQLite in Node.js Project
I am working on implementing Jest in my Node.js project, and I'm using SQLite as the database for testing. However, when I try to run certain tests, I encounter a segmentation fault error. The tests involve a TypeORM repository and an in-memory SQLite database.
The error message I get is: Segmentation fault
Here's a summary of my setup:

Node.js: (version)
Jest: (version)
TypeORM: (version)
SQLite: (version)

In my tests, I'm using an in-memory SQLite database as follows:
beforeEach(async () => {
  dataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'sqlite',
    database: ':memory:',
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [MyEntityModel],
  });
  await dataSource.initialize();
});

The tests work fine in some cases, but in others, I receive the segmentation fault. I’m not sure what's causing this. Has anyone encountered a similar issue when using Jest with SQLite or TypeORM?
I have verified the TypeORM configuration for my entities and checked that my SQLite setup is correct.
